# Need Complex Layout

Tags: html, css

I Need a page layout, which has 2 containers, first one is align center and 2nd container should be full width from right side and align with 1st container from left. for better understanding I've uploading an sample image. and this layout should be responsive. 2nd container should be align from left to above container on every resolution.
[image]

Comment: https://gridbyexample.com/learn/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ should help

Comment: What did you try? Please include some HTML/CSS showing us you tried _something_ before asking on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not be too hard. There may be complications based on headers/navigation, or other wrapper type divs you have in your markup, but this snippet gives the general idea.

Try resizing, should be responsive.

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.full-center {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.full-right {
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-center"></div>
<div class="full-right"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. It's Helpful, Thanks, But I need first container width: 80%; and margin:auto;. please can you help me in this scenario.?

Comment: In my above example, the first container is indeed 80% width (100 - 10 left - 10 right = 80). But I would *not* use `margin: auto` on one div when you want the next to have the same left margin. Setting both `margin-left` and `margin-right` to a percentage allows to repeat that percentage for the `margin-left` of your next container. Why is using `margin auto` required?

Comment: Actually I'm using bootstrap container, but now I think I should be create my own html and css.

Comment: bootstrap's `.container` is useful for sure, but not if you want some content to expand all the way right. Writing your own css is never as bad as you expect it will be :)